# Como pegar o id do banco de cada TD da table html

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Boa Noite

Tenho um botão que guarda o id do banco de cada `<td>` em uma linha, eu envio esse id para abrir um arquivo em outra aba, e agora acrescentei uma segunda função neste botão para pegar o id na coluna subject que guarda o id e fazer um update via ajax.

Está funcionando corretamente, só que o problema é que o ajax só faz o update com o 1 registro da linha 1 da tabela, e com as outras linhas ele simplesmente não atualiza.
Exemplo: se clico no registro numero 20 ele atualiza o registro com o id 1 da tabela. Preciso saber onde está meu erro, e porque ele não pega o id de cada linha que eu clico para fazer a atualização? já quebrei a cabeça e nada. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Meu codigo está assim:

```
<tr>   
<!--  Aqui é a coluna que guarda o id de cada registro   -->          
          <td><input type='hidden' name="subject" id="subject" value="<?php echo $dados['id']?>"><?php echo $dados['id']?></td>
<!--  Aqui o botão que tem duas funções -->
          <td><a href="visualizar.php?protocolo=<?php echo $dados['id'] ?>" type="submit" onclick="inserir_registo()" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Visualizar</a></td>
     </tr> 

<!-- Meu Ajax: -->
 <script>
  function inserir_registo(){

    //dados a enviar, vai buscar os valores dos campos que queremos enviar para a BD
    var dadosajax = {
        'subject' : $("#subject").val()
    };
    pageurl = 'update.php';
    $.ajax({

        //url da pagina
        url: pageurl,
        //parametros a passar
        data: dadosajax,
        //tipo: POST ou GET
        type: 'POST',
        //cache
        cache: false,
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro: Atualizar Registo!!');
        },
        //retorna o resultado da pagina para onde enviamos os dados
        success: function(result)
        { 
            //se foi inserido com sucesso
            if($.trim(result) == '1')
            {
               alert("O seu registo foi atualizado com sucesso!");
               window.location.reload();
            }
            //se foi um erro
            else
            {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar o seu registo!");
            }

        }
    });
}
        </script>
```

E aqui minha pagina update.php que atualiza os registros:

```
<?php

 include("conexao.php");
    $id = $_REQUEST['subject'];

    try
    {
        //insere no BD
        $sql = "UPDATE registros SET status=1 WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        //retorna 1 para no sucesso do ajax saber que foi com inserido sucesso
        echo "1";
    } 
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        //retorna 0 para no sucesso do ajax saber que foi um erro
        echo "0";
    }
?>
```

Me desculpem se não deu pra explicar direito, eu sou iniciante, to começando a estudar essas linguagens agora. Quem puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Vc sabe que não pode repetir um id na mesma página, né?

Comment: @Sam como assim repetir o mesmo id?, cada td da tabela tem seu próprio id, e o botão está pegando o id que guardei nele enviando pra pagina visualizar.php, e usei o ajax nesse mesmo botão para pegar o id da coluna da tabela e fazer o update separado, em outra pagina, a update.php

Comment: Me parece que está repetindo o `id="subject"`. Isso não pode. Um id deve ser único.

Comment: Eu coloquei esse name e o id dentro desse input na coluna td `<td><input type='hidden' name="subject" id="subject" value="<?php echo $dados['id']?>"><?php echo $dados['id']?></td>`  pra poder pegar no ajax, o valor de cada linha, mas não repeti, só coloquei o mesmo name e id

Comment: Mas cada linha tem esse input? Se tiver, está repetindo o id.

Comment: sim tem, mas como eu vou pegar o id de cada linha sem o input?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101619/discussion-between-sam-and-ragnar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está repetindo a id `id="subject"` e passando no `data` do AJAX. Assim irá sempre pegar o primeiro `id="subject"` da página. Um id deve ser único, mas você não precisa fazer isso, criar uma coluna com input escondido para pegar um valor via id.

Basta você passar o id vindo do PHP direto no `onclick` como parâmetro e receber esse valor na função.

Altere o `onclick` para:

```
onclick="inserir_registo('<?php echo $dados['id']?>')"
```

E a abertura da função para:

```
function inserir_registo(id){
```

E o valor do `'subject'` para:

```
'subject': id
```

Comment: era isso msm, ta funcionando perfeitamente, mto obrigado moço! :)